# Openid show images for providers

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership, openid

While trying out the tutorial from

```
http://mvcrocksonasp.net/OAuthWithMVC4
```

Followed the instructions to add the facebook.png like so

```
Dictionary<string, object> facebookExtraData = new Dictionary<string, object>();
facebookExtraData.Add("Icon", "../Images/facebook.png");
```

But it didn't work so anyone able to get the images on the browser ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

came across zocial and this blog post which addresses this specific question

http://www.beabigrockstar.com/customizing-external-login-buttons-in-asp-net-mvc-4/

the sample project is here

https://github.com/jerriep/CustomizeOAuthLoginBranding

the final result looks like so

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I didn't completely gone with your link in detail. But check out with following two links also it may be useful for what you are looking for.

For How to implement OAuth in MVC. 
Check related post in bottom of this link.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2012/08/15/oauth-openid-support-for-webforms-mvc-and-webpages.aspx

To customize provider images. 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2012/08/24/customizing-the-login-ui-when-using-oauth-openid.aspx

Comment: Thanks, tried the code from the 2nd link but couldn't make it work, perhaps because the template uses button submit and the blog changes that to img tag